# Access second resource in Flask Api

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I have a simple Api using Flask, that returns a list of strings using the code below:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from json import dumps

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Product(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'products':['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K']}

class Accounting(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'accounting':['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']}

api.add_resource(Product, '/')
api.add_resource(Accounting, '/')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

When i use the following code, i can access the list that is defined in the Flask api. This lists out the contents of the "product" resource

```
<?php
        $json = file_get_contents('http://product-service/');
        $obj = json_decode($json);
        $products = $obj->products;
        echo "$products[0]";
?>
```

The problem i am having is in accessing the second resource called "accounting". I cannot see the resources or access them when using the following code (with PHP) or even when i just go to the home address of the webpage.

```
<?php
        $json = file_get_contents('http://product-service/');
        $obj = json_decode($json);
        $accounts = $obj->accounting;
        echo "$accounts[0]";
?>
```

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mounting two APIs under one route: the root route "/", I would recommend to seperate the products and accounting into separate API points:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from json import dumps

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Product(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'products':['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K']}

class Accounting(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'accounting':['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']}

api.add_resource(Product, '/products')
api.add_resource(Accounting, '/accounting')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

Comment: Hey it works!, i used your suggestion above and added this code to the php part `$json = file_get_contents('http://product-service/accounting');`thank you :)